# OSNotificationPayload cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, cordova, onesignal, quasar-framework

**THE SITUATION:**

In my [Quasar](https://quasar-framework.org/) hybrid app I need to implement some native functionality to receive [background notifications](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/silent-notifications).

I send Push notification using [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/), from my API.

In the payload I add a `notification_type` that will tell if the notification is silent or not (has to be displayed in the phone or not).

When I receive the notification, I need to read that payload, but I don't manage.

**THE CODE:**

This is the NotificationService:

```
package com.myapp.app;

import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.onesignal.OSNotificationPayload;
import com.onesignal.NotificationExtenderService;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationReceivedResult;

public class NotificationService extends NotificationExtenderService {
   @Override
   protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {

     if (receivedResult != null) {

        JSONObject data = receivedResult.payload;
        // check data - if notification_type is 'silent' than return true otherwise return false
        return false;
     }
   }
}
```

**THE ERROR:**

```
error: incompatible types: OSNotificationPayload cannot be converted to JSONObject
        JSONObject data = receivedResult.payload;
```

[image]

**REFERENCES:**

Here is some example from the OneSignal Android SDK repo:

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/master/Examples/AndroidStudio/app/src/main/java/com/onesignal/example/NotificationExtenderExample.java

It concern background notifications, but in this case they don't read the content of `receivedResult`.

Here is nice example I am following:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=AppHero2/Raffler-Android/Raffler-Android-master/app/src/main/java/com/raffler/app/service/NotificationService.java#

In this case it reads the data like this:
`JSONObject additionalData = receivedResult.payload.additionalData;`

**THE API:**

This is how I send push notifications from my Laravel API

```
private function send_notification_curl($order) {
    $content      = array(
        "en" => "notification message...",
    );
    $fields = array(
        'data' => array(
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'notification_type' => 'silent'
        ),
        'contents' => $content,
        // some other params...
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization: Basic my_key'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I read the content of `receivedResult`?

Can I convert it to a json object?

Do you know why am I getting that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Khalid Taha is correct.

However for my specific case I could use the JSONObject. What was wrong was how I was using it.

If I access data in this way it works:

```
JSONObject additionalData = receivedResult.payload.additionalData;
```

and then I can get the single params like this:

```
final String notificationType = additionalData.optString("notification_type");
```

Probably the property `additionalData` is a built-in property of Notifications.

Answer (score 2):

The payload that you have is in the type of `OSNotificationPayload` not a `JSONObject` so you need to read it like:

```
OSNotificationPayload object = receivedResult.payload;
```

Then you read the values from this object.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This code sample**

```
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
        String message=result.notification.payload.body!=null?result.notification.payload.body:"";
        String title=result.notification.payload.title!=null?result.notification.payload.title:"";
```